# In Python, TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'int'

Tags: python, recommendation-engine, collaborative-filtering

I am doing on making Movie Recommender system by collaborative filtering using Movielens dataset. 
And I follow [this](http://blog.ethanrosenthal.com/2015/11/02/intro-to-collaborative-filtering/) : http://blog.ethanrosenthal.com/2015/11/02/intro-to-collaborative-filtering/

but it doesn't work at ln[8]:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

data = open('ratings.csv')

names = ['user_id','item_id','rating','timestamp']
df = pd.read_csv('ratings.csv', sep=',', names=names)
df.head()

n_users = df.user_id.unique().shape[0]
n_items = df.item_id.unique().shape[0]
print (str(n_users) + ' users')
print (str(n_items) + ' items')

ratings = np.zeros((n_users, n_items))
for row in df.itertuples():
    ratings[row[1]-1, row[2]-1] = row[3]
ratings

sparsity = float(len(ratings.nonzero()[0]))
sparsity /= (ratings.shape[0] * ratings.shape[1])
sparsity *= 100
print ('Sparsity: {:4.2f}%'.format(sparsity))
```

and there is error like this:

```
  line 17, in <module>
    ratings[row[1]-1, row[2]-1] = row[3]
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'int'
```

Comment: The `Exception` is clear - you `row`s hold `str`s.

Answer (score 1):

You read your dataframe from CSV, the default is to read that data as *strings*. You then try to use rows from the dataframe expecting those values to be numbers (subtracting 1 from them) and that fails.

Either specify a `dtype` (to apply to all columns or using a mapping per column), or use pass in a `converters` mapping (mapping column index or column name to a conversion function). Given that the data is all integers (id numbers, ratings and timestamps in seconds since an epoch), a quick fix would be to use `dtype=np.int32` here:

```
df = pd.read_csv('ratings.csv', sep=',', names=names, dtype=np.int32)
```